# How can I trigger an Action Command artificially?

Tags: java, swing

I have two JRadioButton objects with an ActionListener:

```
    for (JRadioButton b : rightRButtons) {
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Unidade")) {
                    disableAllComponents(divisiblePanel);
                    enableAllComponents(unityPanel);
                } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Divisível")) {
                    disableAllComponents(unityPanel);
                    enableAllComponents(divisiblePanel);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Somewhere in the code, I select one of them: `rdbtnCreationDivisible.setSelected(true);`

Those radio buttons, once clicked, are supposed to disable all the components on their respective panels. When I select them using the setSelected method, the components don't get disabled. How can I trigger an action command artificially, so that the ActionListener can "catch" the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things you could try:

First, you could loop through all the `ActionListeners` added to your button, then call it's `actionPerformed()` method, passing in a `ActionEvent` with whatever `ActionCommand` you like:

```
     for(ActionListener al : b.getActionListeners()) {
                al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Unidade") { });
            }
```

Another option would be to replace your `ActionListener` with an `ItemListener`. This would get called when the button is selected/deselected, as opposed to being clicked on:

```
     b.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    //Will get called when you change selection using .setSelected()
                }
            });
```

Nemi has more information on using an `ItemListener` instead of an `ActionListener` on their answer here: [Detecting a JRadioButton state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424738/detecting-a-jradiobutton-state-change)

Comment: No problem, happy I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [create your own event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#ActionEvent-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.String-) and then pass it to [dispatchEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#dispatchEvent-java.awt.AWTEvent-).

```
rdbtnCreationDivisible.setSelected(true);
ActionEvent fakeEvent = new ActionEvent(rdbtnCreationDivisible,
        ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Divisível");
rdbtnCreationDivisible.dispatchEvent(fakeEvent);
```