# Swing: Intercept click on a JRadiobutton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jradiobutton

I want to intercept the click on a JRadioButton in a button group. More precise: When JRadioButton A is chosen and the user clicks on JRadioButton B, I want to show a Yes/No-option pane. Only when the user clicks "Yes", radio button B be will be selected. If the user clicks on "No" nothing is supposed to change.
Is this or rather *how* is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You want to listen for [`ItemEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html)s to know when the first button is selected (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424762/5645656)). You can use [`AbstractButton#isSelected`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()) to check that the other button is selected. Finally, you can use [`JOptionPane#showConfirmDialog(Component, Object, String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-) to prompt the user for "Yes" or "No," and use something like [`AbstractButton#setSelected(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected-boolean-) or [`ButtonGroup#clearSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection--) to control which buttons are selected.

This should get you started down the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much for your both answers. The problem for me is that I have other code listenting when button B is selected. In the suggested code the button B is selected for a short time, even if the users clicks "no". Is there an alternative to actually intercept the selection of button B?

Comment: @felix_w: Edit your question to include a [mre] that has "other code listening when button B is selected" and is also compilable and runnable in any of our IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ItemListener` to the *B* radio button. Refer to [How to Use Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton). The listener is invoked after the selection has changed.

If the *B* button is selected, display a `JOptionPane` asking the user to confirm. Refer to [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). A `JOptionPane` can also be closed by hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key or pressing the **X** button in the top, right corner.

If the user closes the `JOptionPane` by clicking the *YES* button, we do nothing since button *B* is actually already selected. If the user closes the `JOptionPane` any other way, then we need to reset the selection to button *A*.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class Intercep {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JRadioButton aRadioButton;
    private JRadioButton bRadioButton;

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButtons());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtons() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        aRadioButton = new JRadioButton("A");
        bRadioButton = new JRadioButton("B");
        bRadioButton.addItemListener(this::handleItem);
        bg.add(aRadioButton);
        bg.add(bRadioButton);
        panel.add(aRadioButton);
        panel.add(bRadioButton);
        return panel;
    }

    private void handleItem(ItemEvent event) {
        if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                                                       "Are you sure?",
                                                       "Confirm",
                                                       JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            switch (result) {
                case 0:
                    // YES
                    break;
                case -1:
                    // <ESC> or 'X'
                case 1:
                    // NO
                default:
                    aRadioButton.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Intercep().buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Note this line in the above code:

```java
bRadioButton.addItemListener(this::handleItem);
```

This is referred to as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).